# save subscribed image when service is called

Tags: ros, image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

Is there any package to save subscribed image when service is called?

I also want to set filename format ("frame%04i.jpg", for example) to get sequential numbered image and save directory with rosparam.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40805/save-subscribed-image-when-service-is-called/) by [atsushi_tsuda](https://answers.ros.org/users/981/atsushi_tsuda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recommend using OpenCV for writing images. Generate a file name like this:

```
std::ostringstream jpg_filename;
jpg_filename << file_path << "frame" << count << ".jpg";
++count;
```

I guess there should be a variant to create a printf style formatted string too, but I haven't tried anything.

If you are not doing so already, you need to convert your sensor_msgs::Image to cv::Mat format. There is a nice tutorial for that.

And finally save your image.

```
cv::imwrite(jpg_filename.str(), your_cv_mat);
```

Make sure to define OpenCV as a dependency and include the right headers:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
```

Best

Tim

---

Originally posted by [timster](https://answers.ros.org/users/3358/timster/) with karma: 396 on 2013-11-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) on 2013-11-13**:
Small note: Boost.Format should be used over printf in C++.